# The line number in the datagrid (wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf

I choose the value in combobox with datagrid:

```
private void status_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

How do I know the line number in which I chose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
datagrid.SelectedIndex
```

Make sure that `SelectionMode = "Single"`